# document.getElementsByClassName Children NATIVE JS

Tags: javascript

```
<ul class="elephant">
    <li>
        <a class="elephant">Trunk</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

document.getElementsByClassName only returns the < ul > tag. Please help. I only want to target the < a > tag nothing else. Jquery in this particular case is not an option.

Comment: `document.querySelector('ul.elephant a.elephant');`

Comment: _'document.getElementsByClassName only returns the `<ul>` tag'_. No, it doesn't. `document.getElementsByClassName("elephant")[1]` gets you your anchor

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one link you can use `document.querySelector()`

```js
const link = document.querySelector('a.elephant')

link.style.background = 'red'
```

```html
<ul class="elephant">
  <li>
    <a class="elephant">Trunk</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If you have multiple links you can use `document.querySelectorAll()`

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll('a.elephant')

links.forEach(el => el.style.background = 'red')
```

```html
<ul class="elephant">
  <li>
    <a class="elephant">Trunk</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="elephant">Trunk</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```